# Can't install gulp

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, spfx

When I want to reinstall my developer environment, I have some issues with gulp.

```
npm install gulp-cli -g
npm : npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
At line:1 char:1
+ npm install gulp-cli -g
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (npm WARN deprec...-url#deprecated:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
```

I have tried to install different Node version with NVM and I have this issue on all the node versions.

```
nvm list

    14.15.0
    14.6.0
    12.13.1
    12.13.0
```

Is there a way to resolve this issue, so I could have an SPFX developer environment again?

Comment: That's just a deprecation WARNing. Not an ERRor ...

Comment: @Derpirscher, why isn't gulp not installed then?

Comment: How do you check if it's installed?

Comment: I don't know. but these warnings are not the main issue ... Have you anything in your logs that starts with `npm ERR`?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I check it with gulp -v. This isn't showing any information

Comment: @derpirscher No only the warning.

Comment: WHAT is the output of `gulp -v`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation, I figured out that gulp wasn't installed because of an error with NVM.

NVM wasn't showing which version I was using, and also not changing the version.

To fix this

I had to delete the folder located at C:\Program Files\nodejs

And then run NVM use {version}
Install gulp-cli again and now Gulp is installed

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, what you are showing is a deprecation warning, so gulp-cli should be installed. Use the following to see if gulp-cli is installed:

```
npm ls -g --depth=0
```

which should report the version of gulp-cli.

You can also run

```
gulp -v
```

This will return the "CLI version:" and "Local version:" of gulp. The local version will be listed as Unknown unless your are in the folder with a SPFx project where "npm i" has been run, where Gulp commands will also be available (gulp build, gulp serve, etc.)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Tyler2P for fixing the formatting to use code blocks. Looks great!